# Numpy matrix to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a numpy user-item matrix, each row corresponds to an user and each columns corresponds to an item.
I want to convert the matrix in a pandas DataFrame like the one as follows:

```
   user  item  rating
0     1  1907     4.0
1     1  1028     5.0
2     1   608     4.0
3     1  2692     4.0
4     1  1193     5.0
```

I use the following code to generate a DataFrame:

```
predictions = pd.DataFrame(data=pred)
predictions = predictions.stack().reset_index(name='rating')
predictions.columns = ['user', 'item', 'rating']
```

and I obtain a df like this:

```
        user  item    rating
0          0     0  5.000000
1          0     1  0.000000
2          0     2  0.000000
3          0     3  0.000000
```

Is there a way in pandas to map each values in user and items columns to a value stored in list? User with value 0 should be mapped with the 1st value in user list, user with value 5 with the 6th element in user list and so on...
I'm trying using:

```
predictions[["user"]].apply(lambda value: users[value])
```

but I got an IndexError I don't understand because my users list is of size 96

```
IndexError: ('index 96 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 96', 'occurred at index user')
```

Comment: what does `pred` look like?

Comment: @akilat90 pred is my numpy matrix

Comment: Of course! Can you show how it looks like?

Comment: Also, what is the list that you refer by `Is there a way in pandas to map each values in user and items columns to a value stored in list? `. And, if you include the expected dataframe, it will be easy to understand for someone else.

Comment: I agree with @akilat90 - it's a bit unclear what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

my fault was in this code:

```
while not session.should_stop():
    predictions = session.run(decoder_op)
    pred = np.vstack((pred, predictions))
```

just replaced with:

```
np.vstack((pred, predictions))
```

and it works like a charm with:

```
predictions['user'] = predictions['user'].map(lambda value: users[value])
predictions['item'] = predictions['item'].map(lambda value: items[value])
```